# does nutch have web service API?

Tags: java, nutch

I know that Nutch has commands that can be used in a java project, but does Nutch have web services as API? (for example, like ElasticSearch REST API)

Answer (score 1):

In this document (http://www.apache.org/dist/nutch/2.1/CHANGES-2.1.txt) you see that nutch has a REST API.
here is what it looks like: http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-2.0/index.html

What is your specific question?

Comment: I want to know how to write a program that uses nutch's core api and starts a crawl job. I don't want to use terminal commands and I want my own program to set the configuration options. Is there a tutorial for that?